# Rules from excel in java web based applications

Tags: java, excel, web-applications, rule-engine, business-rules

I have been trying to find the right design/toolset which can help our business users. They have enormous data in excel files which they push through to various excel formulas and calculations usually and mostly on a row by row basis and vlookups from other sheets.
In trying to design a system for them, i want to enable them to define the business rules so that we can stick to designing and implementing the system, which will change state according to the business rules defined ?
What current stack of technologies would be able to support this ?

So basically something like this -> we dump all their (up to 400k+ and growing) data safely assuming that all rules and formulas will be applied on a row by row basis, into a database. We setup a web-page for them to author rules. The java runtime kicks in on the rules defined to apply them on a row by row basis.

Any design technology/design which can nearly match the computation power of excel and ease of defining rules for business analysts ? Any pointers to design/setup will be appreciated .

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment related to excel based rules applications: Try out the PowerPivot solution with office 10 which can handle millions of rows of data in seconds. i think it is great if you already have the necessary infrastructure in place. While we get that setup in the interim i believe drools will help us along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used JBoss rules in our project where we required thousands of rules to be maintained by users. It's based on Rete algorithm which is one of the fastest pattern matching algorithms. JBoss provides full fledge solution covering rules authoring, approval workflow, centralized rules repository, rules engine, eclipse plugin, support for DSL etc.

The problem with JBoss rules is that the core rules are written using either it's scripting language MVEL or XML. I think say tactically they are more programmers option then end users option so you might want to invest in their rules's authoring/management product called governer. The governor provides good UI for rules authoring. But the problem we faced was that for some modules they did not want rules building UI to be shown as its provided by governer to their end users as it seemed to be very much complex for those cases. We happened to use JBoss rules API to form rules in backend by showing very simple UI to end users. Their API really works well. Another option in that case could be leveraging their DSL support to make rules like plain English like statements.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i am quite new to rules based systems. I am just reading up various documentation sources and trying to understand a basic architecture setup for rules based systems. For instance in a typical MVC web app, suppose i have managed to input my target entities into their respective tables. Now i load the entities on which i want to run the rules in the rules engine (the rules would be across entities because of relational mappings), how and when does the rule engine work on the dataset ? I think i need to read some more docs on rule based systems ..any pointers ?

Comment: you can use a scheduler service ( Quartz for eg.  ) to invoke the rule engine and pass the data objects on which the rules are to be executed.then you can update the "status" column in the DB records as "rule applied".

Alternatively , create a webservice from the rule engine , invoke the webservice whenever required.

Comment: As Tito said, you can schedule a batch. We had Rules Management Services taking care of rules management. And a Rule Matching Utility to be used by any service which needs to perform rule matching against given domain object(s). Regarding using entities as is with JBoss rules, they provide very good way of integrating java objects with their rule definition. For e.g. if you have object structure like Customer -> Address -> zipcode and you want to write a rule like for a given zip code there is 10% discount. You just need to import java classes in the rule file same as import stmt & it in rule.

Answer (score 1):

For rules, you can take a look at JBoss Drools. It easily integrates with Hibernate which you can use for persisting data into the database. With drools you have the advantage of drools guvnor which can be used as a frontend for business folks to edit the rules.

Comment: how would a typical flowstate diagram look like ? would i need to invoke the rules on a per row basis ? what is the performance like if u have used this in any application, can you share some details ?

Answer (score 1):

IBM ILOG Jrules is a paid product from IBM , you can try out the trial version for 90 days though.  ILOG is fully integrated with eclipse , it comes with a rule team server ( rule repository,version control ) and rule execution server, plus the rule studio,where you can generate the rules.

You can first create the object model as pojo classes in java and then import this pojo to your eclipse project and ilog will create english like language constructs for all the classes, you can then write a rule which looks like this

```
if the age of the person is more than 18 then
allow the person to vote
else
do not allow the person to vote
```

The above rule can implemented in either the rule studio by technical users, or the business users can connect to the rule team server web interface and can author rules from a web browser.

Ilog provides excellent rule unit testing tool called DVS , with which you can test the rules using excel sheet. Even the business users can test the rules from the web interface of the rule team server.

In ILOG we can choose between a number of rule execution algorithm like RetePlus , sequential etc . The IBM's documentation is comprehensive and lot of samples are provided to get you started.

Comment: This looks like in the direction i am looking forward to. I guess i need to ramp up my knowledge on how rules based systems work. However in order to user ILOG Jrules it must essentially be deployed within a Websphere server instance ? A lock-in is something i something i try to resist.

Comment: the current version of ILOG comes packaged with websphere , but rules can be deployed in tomcat or even JBOSS , the rule team server and the rule execution server are just 'war' files which can be deployed in any j2ee app server. here is a quick overview of what jrules can do - its not the vendor document,so whatever mentioned in the doc will not be biased. [link](http://logic.stanford.edu/POEM/externalpapers/iRules/ILOG_JRules6_Bloor_Report.pdf)

Comment: thanks for the insights into the product, however if were to go paid i  happened to chance upon microsoft PowerPivot with office 10. It works great with analysts who like the excel view of the world.